# How to get address of a register: ARM Cortex A8?

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, cortex-a8

I want to get physical address of a co-processor register of ARM Cortex a8, say c9-User Enable Register (USEREN).

How can I get it ?

Thank you !!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get the address of a co-processor register. You'd access them with `MRC` and `MCR` instructions.

Comment: Thank you Tangrs !!

But while writing to a particular register, it is not actually reflecting in exact location.


say, I am writing to a register and accessing it gives me proper value. Moving into some other module and accessing gives default value..

Any idea ?

Comment: Doing this in Kernel mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all registers need to exist in a memory address. Co-processor registers are a good example for this. Co-processors are separate execution units and most of the time only way to access their registers are via instructions like [mcr / mrc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/Cihfifej.html).

Comment: Thank you Auselen for your detail description.

Can you please clarify me why I am unable to write to any cp15 registers ?

writing are not done, as fetching them from different module or different functions from same module gives me default value instead of the modified one.

Specifically I am talking about User Enable register: asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 0\n\t" :: "r"(1));

Comment: I would say you probably have some other problem.